# Fastest method to filter an array for typeahead

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I am wondering what the fastest way to filter an array of objects for a typeahead is?

Given a list of 10000 or more items similiar to this:

```
[{name: "ben"}, {name: "Alex"}, {name: "mary"}]
```

I can filter them for a typeahead using the `Array.prototype.filter` method, but I'm seeing quite a bit of lag time before getting results back. Is there a better way to filter large lists based on keyboard input?

Here is my current implemenation:

```
const list = [{...}] //list of 10000 or more objects with a name property

function getFilteredList(input) {
    const reg = new RegExp(input.toLowerCase(), 'i');
    return list.filter(i => reg.test(i.name));
}
```

Is there a way to filter a list that is faster or has better performance than using the `Array.prototype.filter` method?

Comment: Does that filter even work? If `list` contains objects, calling `reg.test({name: "ben"})` would not seem to work... You'll want to look at "debouncing" your method calls too.

Comment: It really depends on the actual data. Probably removing the `RegExp` call would make it even faster. For the example data, I'd flatten the array to just be the names all set as lowercase, then lowercase the input as you get it and do the compare with `indexOf`. When comparing performance, the only way to get the "right" answer is to try something, test, then try something else.

Comment: Thanks Mike! You're right I will have to update my example for the filter RegEx to work. You are right that testing and seeing what works is the way to go. I hadn't thought of index of on an array of strings. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a couple of tests, seems like all traditional loop is three times (more or less) faster for big arrays than filter though much more verbose. I think I'd stick to filter just for clarity's sake.

```js
const list = []; //list of 10000 or more objects with a name property
var res;

for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  list.push({
    name: "a" + i
  });
}

function getFilteredList(input) {
  const reg = new RegExp(input.toLowerCase(), 'i');
  return list.filter(i => reg.test(i.name));
}

function getFilteredList2(input) {
  const reg = new RegExp(input.toLowerCase(), 'i');
  let len = list.length;
  let i = 0;
  let res = [];
  let el;
  
  while (i !== len) {
    el = list[i++]; 
    if (reg.test(el.name)) {
      res.push(el);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.time("Filter test");
res = getFilteredList('a999999');
console.timeEnd("Filter test");
console.log(res[0]);

console.time("Filter test2");
res = getFilteredList2('a999999');
console.timeEnd("Filter test2");
console.log(res[0]);
```

Comment: Averaging 72ms vs 46ms in my tests. I'm not sure that's a significant difference, especially since there's more variability between test runs (I got 123ms for `filter` in one run) than there is between the two tests.

Comment: Here I get 99ms vs 30ms more or less consistently though I agree with you in that it's not significant at all. Like I said, I'd go for filter though I was curious about traditional loop times. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about console.time. That's why I asked. I was not sure how to test different implementations.